# VGG16 location in disk

Tags: python

i can't download the VGG16 model via jupyter notebook because it always reset the connection. 
so i decided download it via url buat i don't know how to call the weight to my model. what should i do? im very new to this topics.

```
  [1]: http://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
```

this is the code to call in my model

```
vgg16 = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
```

Answer (score 2):

As given in the [FAQs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#where-is-the-keras-configuration-file-stored), all keras data is stored in `~/.keras/`. By default, Keras models are stored in `~/.keras/models/`. Just move your downloaded weights to this folder and your code should work fine. Please note that the name of the file should be the same as given in the download url. In this case it is: `vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5`.

Comment: I just came across this issue personally, for Windows, the files are stored at `C:\Users\YourUserName\.keras\models` (in my case the system drive was `C`)